# Stream the textbox content of the streamer to the textbox of a viewer using WebRTC one to many broadcast

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, webrtc, transcription

I am a beginner and I am trying to implement a WebRTC one-to-many broadcast that streams the textbox content. I am looking to stream the textbox content as it is the output of transcription from the microphone input. So, please help me in figuring out how one can stream the textbox content of the streamer to the textbox of a viewer.

Comment: This is not the typical project undertaken by a `beginner` and is quite involved/complex. Please add all relevant code that you have currently and clarify where it fails or where you have problems.

Comment: i suggest using websockets instead. if you don't need to send the actual video there is no point in using webrtc